# F# missing type constraint

Tags: f#, type-constraints

In the following code, note the type constraint for get_Zero:

```
type Wrapper<'t> = { Data : 't[] }

let compute<'t
    when 't : (static member get_Zero : unit -> 't)
    and 't : (static member (~-) : 't -> 't)
    and 't : (static member (+) : 't * 't -> 't)>
        (wrapper : Wrapper<'t>) =
    wrapper.Data
        |> Seq.mapi (fun i value -> (i, value))
        |> Seq.sumBy (fun (i, value) ->
            if i % 2 = 0 then value
            else -value)
```

Even though I already have an explicit type constraint, I'm still getting the following compiler error on the call to Seq.sumBy:

> A type parameter is missing a constraint 'when  ^t : (static member
>   get_Zero : ->  ^t)'

Anyone know what's going on here? Thanks.

Comment: Apart from this question already having a very valid answer, I'd like to stress that when you use SRTP (statically resolved type parameters) as you are doing with these `static member` etc constraints, then the function must be `inline` and instead of using `'T`, use `^t` instead (meaning: `^`, not `'`). See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trying to make downstream static member constraints explicit can be an exercise in frustration, and, fortunately, it's seldom necessary. Just mark the function `inline` and let them be inferred.

```
let inline compute (wrapper : Wrapper<_>) =
    wrapper.Data
    |> Seq.mapi (fun i value -> (i, value))
    |> Seq.sumBy (fun (i, value) ->
        if i % 2 = 0 then value
        else -value)
```

The correct signature is:

```
let inline compute<'t
            when 't : (static member Zero : 't)
            and 't : (static member (~-) : 't -> 't)
            and 't : (static member (+) : 't * 't -> 't)>
```

(You'll notice the signature in the error message isn't even valid syntax: `when ^t : (static member get_Zero : -> ^t)`. This is part of what I mean by frustrating.)

Comment: Why the inline version works? The compiler infers the constraints. `sumBy` is inline, and its constraints are propagated to the consuming function by marking it inline as well.

Comment: This works, but doesn't actually answer the question. It also doesn't seem to work with type extensions that call the "compute" function:

`type Wrapper<'t> with member inline wrapper.Compute = wrapper |> compute`

Comment: @brianberns: I updated my answer with the working signature. The type extension doesn't work because it uses the generic argument defined on the type, and constraints on type-level generic args must be explicit.